# Second-order perturbation jellium revisited

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, many-body

The second order correction to the energy of an homogeneous electron gas (jellium) is given rougly by $$E^{(2)}=\frac{Ne^2}{2a_0}(\epsilon_2^r+\epsilon_2^b)$$ with two terms, a direct term
given by $$\epsilon_2^r=-\frac{3}{8\pi^5}\int\text{d}q\frac{1}{q^4}\int_{|\vec{p}+\vec{q}|>1}\text{d}k^3\int_{|\vec{p}+\vec{q}|>1}\text{d}^3p\frac{\theta(1-k)\theta(1-p)}{q^2+\vec{q}\cdot(\vec{k}+\vec{p})}$$
and an exchange term by
$$\epsilon_2^b=\frac{3}{16\pi^5}\int\text{d}q\frac{1}{q^2}\int_{|\vec{p}+\vec{q}|>1}\text{d}k^3\int_{|\vec{p}+\vec{q}|>1}\text{d}^3p\frac{\theta(1-k)\theta(1-p)}{(\vec{q}+\vec{k}+\vec{p})^2[q^2+\vec{q}\cdot(\vec{k}+\vec{p})]}$$

An attempt to obtain such a result can be seen in [How to calculate the second-order pertubation in an electron gas?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/525116/how-to-calculate-the-second-order-pertubation-in-an-electron-gas/531018#531018)

However I have a problem, if we are discussing second order corrections there is a factor 2 between direct and exchange terms that is bothering me.

### Original derivation and issue

In the original paper by [W. Macke, Z. Naturforsch. 5a](https://doi.org/10.1515/zna-1950-0402). 192 (1950), Wacke writes in Eq. 17, that

$$V_{0n}=V_{n0}=\frac{e^2h^2}{\pi v}\left\{\frac{\delta_{s_1's_1}\delta_{s_2's_2}}{\mathfrak g^2}-\frac{\delta_{s_1's_2}\delta_{s_2's_1}}{(\mathfrak p_1-\mathfrak p_2 +\mathfrak g)^2}\right\}
$$
where $V_{n0}$ is the amplitude in the second order perturbation theory:
$$E^{(2)}=\sum_{n\neq0} \frac{V_{n0}V_{0n}}{E_{0}-E_n}$$
where $|0\rangle$ indicates the ground state of a non-interacting electron gas.

As $V_{0n}V_{n0}=|V_{0n}|^2$, I was expecting the term in brackets to become
$$\left\{\frac{\delta_{s_1's_1}\delta_{s_2's_2}}{\mathfrak g^2}-\frac{\delta_{s_1's_2}\delta_{s_2's_1}}{(\mathfrak p_1-\mathfrak p_2 +\mathfrak g)^2}\right\}^2=\frac{\delta_{s_1's_1}\delta_{s_2's_2}}{\mathfrak g^4}+\frac{\delta_{s_1's_2}\delta_{s_2's_1}}{(\mathfrak p_1-\mathfrak p_2 +\mathfrak g)^4}-\frac{2\delta_{s_1's_1}\delta_{s_2's_2}\delta_{s_1's_2}\delta_{s_2's_1}}{\mathfrak g^2(\mathfrak p_1-\mathfrak p_2 +\mathfrak g)^2}$$

However Macke, in the equation just below equation 19, writes
$$E^{(2)}=-\frac{m}{4}\left(\frac{v^2}{h^3}\right)^3\left(\frac{e^2h^2}{\pi v}\right)\sum_{ss'}\int\frac{d\mathfrak p_1 d\mathfrak p_2 d\mathfrak g}{(\mathfrak p_1-\mathfrak p_2 +\mathfrak g)\mathfrak g}\\
\cdot\left\{\frac{\delta_{s_1's_1}\delta_{s_2's_2}}{\mathfrak g^4}+\frac{\delta_{s_2's_2}\delta_{s_1's_1}}{(\mathfrak p_1-\mathfrak p_2 +\mathfrak g)^4}-\frac{2\delta_{s_1's_1}\delta_{s_2's_2}\delta_{s_1's_2}\delta_{s_2's_1}}{\mathfrak g^2(\mathfrak p_1-\mathfrak p_2 +\mathfrak g)^2}\right\}$$
take a close look at the symbols in the Dirac deltas of the second term. With Wacke's construction I get his result but I do not know how he makes that squaring of the amplitude. Did he made a mistake? I do not understand also how is he handling the spin sums. The paper is in German, so I am not completely sure if there is a key step there. My derivation can be seen below.

### My derivation

The Hamiltonian could be divided into $$H_0=\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}a^\dagger_{\mathbf{k},\sigma}a_{\mathbf{k},\sigma}$$ and the perturbation $$V=\frac{e^2}{2v}\sum_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}',\mathbf{q}\neq0}\sum_{\sigma,\sigma'}\frac{4\pi}{q^2}a^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{q},\sigma}a^\dagger_{\mathbf{p}+\mathbf{q},\sigma'}a_{\mathbf{p},\sigma'}a_{\mathbf{k},\sigma}$$
where $v$ is the volume of the electron gas.

Here is my take on the second order term, in units of $k_{\rm F}$,
$$E^{(2)}\propto-\sum_{\mathbf p\mathbf p' \mathbf q'}\sum_{\lambda \lambda '}\frac{\Theta(|\mathbf p-\mathbf q'|-1)\Theta(|\mathbf p'+\mathbf q'|-1)\Theta(1- p)\Theta(1-p')}{(q')^2+\mathbf{q}'\cdot(\mathbf p'-\mathbf p)}\\
\times\left|\sum_{\sigma \sigma'}\sum_{q}\sum_{\mathbf k \mathbf k'}\frac{1}{q^2} \langle \mathrm 0|a_{\mathbf p\lambda}^\dagger a^\dagger_{\mathbf p'\lambda'} a_{\mathbf p'+\mathbf q',\lambda '} a_{\mathbf p-\mathbf q',\lambda} a^\dagger_{\mathbf k-\mathbf q,\sigma} a^\dagger_{\mathbf k'+\mathbf q,\sigma '} a_{\mathbf k'\sigma'} a_{\mathbf k\sigma}|0\rangle  \right|^2$$
where $\mathbf p\mathbf p '\mathbf q'$ (spins $\lambda,\lambda'$) are the sum over $|n\rangle=a^\dagger_{\mathbf p-\mathbf q',\lambda} a^\dagger_{\mathbf p'+\mathbf q',\lambda '} a_{\mathbf p'\lambda'} a_{\mathbf p\lambda}|0\rangle$ and $\mathbf k,\mathbf k' \mathbf q$ (spins $\sigma\sigma'$) associated with the Coulomb interaction. The amplitude can be calculated to be
$$\langle \mathrm 0|a_{\mathbf p\lambda}^\dagger a^\dagger_{\mathbf p'\lambda'} a_{\mathbf p'+\mathbf q',\lambda '} a_{\mathbf p-\mathbf q',\lambda} a^\dagger_{\mathbf k-\mathbf q,\sigma} a^\dagger_{\mathbf k'+\mathbf q,\sigma '} a_{\mathbf k'\sigma'} a_{\mathbf k\sigma}|0\rangle  \\
=(\delta_{\mathbf p-\mathbf q',\mathbf k-\mathbf q}\delta_{\lambda \sigma}\delta_{\mathbf p'+\mathbf q',\mathbf k'+\mathbf q}\delta_{\lambda' \sigma'}-\delta_{\mathbf p-\mathbf q',\mathbf k'+\mathbf q}\delta_{\lambda \sigma'}\delta_{\mathbf p'+\mathbf q',\mathbf k-\mathbf q}\delta_{\lambda' \sigma})(\delta_{\mathbf p,\mathbf k}\delta_{\lambda \sigma}\delta_{\mathbf p',\mathbf k'}\delta_{\lambda' \sigma'}-\delta_{\mathbf p,\mathbf k'}\delta_{\lambda \sigma'}\delta_{\mathbf p',\mathbf k}\delta_{\lambda' \sigma})$$

if we sum over $\mathbf k,\mathbf k'$ we get
$$=\delta_{\mathbf q',\mathbf q}\delta_{\lambda\sigma}\delta_{\lambda'\sigma'}-\delta_{\mathbf q'-\mathbf p+\mathbf p',\mathbf q}\delta_{\lambda \sigma'}\delta_{\lambda \sigma}\delta_{\lambda '\sigma'}\delta_{\lambda' \sigma}-\delta_{\mathbf q,\mathbf p-\mathbf p'-\mathbf q'}\delta_{\lambda \lambda'}\delta_{\lambda \sigma'}\delta_{\lambda \sigma}\delta_{\lambda '\sigma'}\delta_{\lambda' \sigma}+\delta_{\mathbf q',-\mathbf q}\delta_{\lambda\sigma}\delta_{\lambda'\sigma'}$$
changing $\mathbf q\to-\mathbf q$ for some of the sums, we have
$$=2\delta_{\mathbf q',\mathbf q}\delta_{\lambda\sigma}\delta_{\lambda'\sigma'}-2\delta_{\mathbf q'-\mathbf p+\mathbf p',\mathbf q}\delta_{\lambda \sigma'}\delta_{\lambda \sigma}\delta_{\lambda '\sigma'}\delta_{\lambda' \sigma}$$
similar to Eq. 17 in Macke, summing over $\sigma\sigma'$ we have
$$=2\delta_{\mathbf q',\mathbf q}-2\delta_{\mathbf q'-\mathbf p+\mathbf p',\mathbf q}\delta_{\lambda \lambda'}$$

Putting it back,in the square and sums we have
$$E^{(2)}\propto-\sum_{\mathbf p\mathbf p' \mathbf q'}\sum_{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}\frac{\Theta(|\mathbf p-\mathbf q'|-1)\Theta(|\mathbf p'+\mathbf q'|-1)\Theta(1- p)\Theta(1-p')}{(q')^2+\mathbf{q}'\cdot(\mathbf p'-\mathbf p)}\\
\times\left|
\frac{1}{q'^2}-\frac{\delta_{\lambda_1\lambda_2}}{|\mathbf q'+\mathbf p'-\mathbf p|^2}\right|^2\tag{1}\label{this}
$$
$$=-\sum_{\mathbf p\mathbf p' \mathbf q'}\sum_{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}\frac{\Theta(|\mathbf p-\mathbf q'|-1)\Theta(|\mathbf p'+\mathbf q'|-1)\Theta(1- p)\Theta(1-p')}{(q')^2+\mathbf{q}'\cdot(\mathbf p'-\mathbf p)}\\
\times\left[ 
\frac{1}{q'^4}-\frac{2\delta_{\lambda_1\lambda_2}}{q'^2|\mathbf q+\mathbf p'-\mathbf p|^2}+\frac{\delta_{\lambda_1\lambda_2}}{|\mathbf q'+\mathbf p'-\mathbf p|^4}\right]
$$
$$=-2\sum_{\mathbf p\mathbf p' \mathbf q'}\frac{\Theta(|\mathbf p-\mathbf q'|-1)\Theta(|\mathbf p'+\mathbf q'|-1)\Theta(1- p)\Theta(1-p')}{(q')^2+\mathbf{q}'\cdot(\mathbf p'-\mathbf p)}\\
\times\left[ 
\frac{2}{q'^4}-\frac{2}{q'^2|\mathbf q+\mathbf p'-\mathbf p|^2}+\frac{1}{|\mathbf q'+\mathbf p'-\mathbf p|^4}\right]
$$
$$=-2\sum_{\mathbf p\mathbf p' \mathbf q'}\frac{\Theta(|\mathbf p-\mathbf q'|-1)\Theta(|\mathbf p'+\mathbf q'|-1)\Theta(1- p)\Theta(1-p')}{(q')^2+\mathbf{q}'\cdot(\mathbf p'-\mathbf p)}\\
\times\left[ 
\frac{3}{q'^4}-\frac{2}{q'^2|\mathbf q'+\mathbf p'-\mathbf p|^2}\right]
$$

where the factors of 2 come from the sum over the spins and the fraction of $1/|\mathbf q'+\mathbf p-\mathbf p'|^4$ disappears by a change of variables and is added to the $1/q^4$ term, however as it has  $\delta_{\lambda_1\lambda_2}$ term it only contributes a factor of 1 and not 2. Eq.\eqref{this} is similar to Macke's Eq. 17, however we do not agree on the sums. For me part of the sum is inside the $V_{n0}$ while Macke has the sum outside (sums over 4 spin numbers). Thus I end up with a direct term that is 3/2 times larger than the exchange term, which is not what is expected by Macke (2:1).

I have checked G. Giuliani's book *Quantum Theory of the Electron Liquid* but there is no hint of what happens with that square. Just a simple "*keeping a careful record of the multiplicities of the various terms*".

Comment: Isn't it just a typo?

Comment: @adam I do not think it is a typo, if not there would be an extra term $(1/(q+k+p)'^4)$. To be clear there would be a square term $|1/q^2 +\delta_{\lambda_1\lambda_2}/(|q+k+p|'^2)|^2$ thus even with a change of variable the direct term would contribute 3 times the exchange, not 2

Comment: It is hard to fill the gap without more details in the derivations of the various expressions. But it feels like $|\sum_{p',k',q'}\frac1{q'^2}...|^2$ should become $\sum_{p',k',q'}\frac1{q'^2}...\sum_{p'',k'',q''}\frac1{q''^2}(...)^*$, right?

Comment: @Adam I am hoping to avoid the "check my results" situation, however I cannot seem to get it right. Which step would you like me to add? Some are already in the linked answer. I agree with your statement , for me $|\sum 1/q'^2|^2=\sum' 1/q'\sum'' 1/q''^2$ so in the end there are three sums (and not two) one for variables $q$ coming from the sum over state $|n\rangle$, one for $q'$ and one for $q''$. This does not coincide with the solution in the link.

Comment: Worse than "check my results" is "redo the calculation on your own to see where the problem is" ;-) If at least we have what $|n\rangle$, $E_n$ and $\langle 0|H_1|n\rangle$ are, it is simpler to see where the problem is (e.g. I don't have the book with me)

Comment: @Adam thanks for taking interest. I was mostly checking on the amplitude squared thing. I will update the question in my own derivation later today.

Comment: I don't see how the square amplitude thing could be wrong. My gut feeling is that it is a mix of a typo in the other answer plus an error on your side. But that's hard to check without all the information. Note that in the three sums we discussed above, two will disappear in the end. Probably giving a $\delta_{q,q'}\delta_{q,q''}$?

Comment: @Adam thanks again, I added a derivation and the link to the original paper, I hope it helps.

Comment: I do not understand your story about "$1/|+−′|^4$
  disappears by a change of variables and is added to the $1/^4$
 term, however as it has $\delta_{\lambda_1\lambda_2}$ term in it". On the third line of Eq. 2, you have already performed the sum. What is the explicit change of variable you are using?

Comment: @Adam sorry there were two typos, there was an extra $q'^2$ in what I wrote and it should be $|\mathbf q'+\mathbf p' -\mathbf p|^4$. The change of variables for that last term is $\mathbf q'+\mathbf p' -\mathbf p \to \mathbf q '$. Note that the Heavisides change accordingly but just exchange sides. If the $|\mathbf q'+\mathbf p' -\mathbf p|^4$ term does not add to the other, then where does it go?

Comment: There is a difference between your expression and the one of Macke. He has the same spin factors for the $1/q'^4$ and $1/(q'+p'-p)^4$. Then, from his expression, using the change of variables, one recovers his result.

Comment: @Adam Macke in equation 17 has the same factors as I. In eq. 19-20 he has different factors. It comes down to the squared of the potential again. How does squaring eq.17 leads to a $1/(q'+p'-p)^4$ factor that has different spin factors to that of $1/q^2(q'+p'-p)^2$ when both come from the same term squared.

Comment: Just squaring his $V_{n0}$ gives exactly his $E^{(2)}$ given on the left column of p. 197 (in the second term, you could exchange $s_1'$ and ^s_2'$ to make it more obvious). Then summing over spins gives Eq. 20. This is clearly not equivalent to your Eq. 2, so I think your error might be in deriving it.

Comment: @Adam thanks again. I think you have a point. I am still not sure what do you mean. Would you agree that if I have (from Wacke eq 17) $[\delta_{s_1's_1}\delta_{s_2's_2}/q^2-\delta_{s_1's_2}\delta_{s_2's_1}/Q^2]^2=\delta_{s_1's_1}\delta_{s_2's_2}/q^2-2\delta_{s_1's_1}\delta_{s_2's_2}\delta_{s_1's_2}\delta_{s_2's_1}/Q^2q^2 +\delta_{s_1's_2}\delta_{s_2's_1}/Q^4$? However, Wacke seems to write $\delta_{s_1's_1}\delta_{s_2's_2}/q^2-2\delta_{s_1's_1}\delta_{s_2's_2}\delta_{s_1's_2}\delta_{s_2's_1}/Q^2q^2 +\delta_{s_1's_1}\delta_{s_2's_2}/Q^4$. Please feel free to write a response.

Comment: @Adam I think I get what you are pointing at, but then I would argue that $V_{n0}$ in Eq.17 should include the sum over the spins inside of it (because it is the sum of the interaction not of the state n), which after the sum removes completely any dependence in spins, so both terms exchange and direct terms have the same 1 to 1 factor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145279/discussion-between-adam-and-mauricio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Adam permission's, here I copy the solution to this problem:

> you assume that your excited state is of the form (in his notation) $|n\rangle=|p_1 s_1,p_2 s_2; p_1' s_1, p_2' s_2\rangle$, that is, you restric the holes and particles to have the same spins (no primes for the last two spin states $s_1$ and $s_2$) whereas he allows different spin states ($s_1'$ and $s_2'$)

This point resolves the issue. In my calculation I assumed,  $|n\rangle=a^\dagger_{\mathbf p-\mathbf q',\lambda} a^\dagger_{\mathbf p'+\mathbf q',\lambda '} a_{\mathbf p'\lambda'} a_{\mathbf p\lambda}|0\rangle$ (2 spin sums) while I should instead unrestrict the spin variables as in the correct  $|n\rangle=a^\dagger_{\mathbf p-\mathbf q',s_1} a^\dagger_{\mathbf p'+\mathbf q',s_2} a_{\mathbf p's_1'} a_{\mathbf p s_2'}|0\rangle$ (sum over 4 spins variables).

I recover the expected result now, without the right factors of 2, which might be related to double counting. But that is a question for another moment.